# Why does adding logging changes the way exceptions are handled?

Tags: python, logging, exception

*Note: after having solved the problem, per my last comment to the answer: the tracebacks are not unhandled exceptions, they are **logging messages from urllib3**, so my last question is void (= everything is caught correctly)*

I test the [availability of an Elasticsearch server](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/api-conventions.html) by sending a [`.info()`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.info) request and catching the exception. The code below is

```
import elasticsearch

### removing the code from here to a marker further down (basically the logging part makes the handling work fine

import os
import logging
import logging.handlers
import logging.config
import tempfile
import random
import arrow
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger

class CustomLogger():
    """
    whereform: usually __name__ = the name of the script
    index: th eindex to log to, ideally a group of activities (nessus for instance)
    type: an explicit type to log to, ideally an activity withon the group above
    """
    # the start date of the logging, a common date for all handlers
    startdate = arrow.now('local').format('YYYY_MM_DD__HH_mm_ss')

    def __init__(self):
        # what LogRecords we want, in which order
        rec = ['asctime', 'created', 'filename', 'funcName', 'lineno', 'processName', 'levelname', 'message']

        # initializing the logging module, getting all information from DEBUG up
        # the handler is randomized to have different names
        self.rootLogger = logging.getLogger(str(random.random()))
        self.rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # console
        consolefmt = logging.Formatter(
            " | ".join(["%({0:s})s".format(i) for i in rec])
        )
        consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
        consoleHandler.setFormatter(consolefmt)
        consoleHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

        # json file
        jsonfmt = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
            " | ".join(["%({0:s})s".format(i) for i in rec])
        )
        #jsonfmt = "{'timestamp': '%(created)f'," + ','.join(["'{0:s}': %({0:s})s".format(i) for i in rec]) + "}"
        logdir = "/var/log/GetNessusScans/{date}/".format(date=CustomLogger.startdate)
        try:
            os.makedirs(logdir)
        except:
            # the directory exists already
            pass
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
                mode='w',
                delete=False,
                prefix=logdir,
                suffix=".log"
        ) as f:
            logfilename = f.name
        # make it r by everyone
        #os.chmod(f.name, 0666)
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(logfilename)
        fileHandler.setFormatter(jsonfmt)
        fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler)


log = CustomLogger().rootLogger
### end of suspicious code, removing everything from this line up removes the problem

import elasticsearch

# initialize dataabase - the host does not exist for the purpose of the example
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch(hosts="http://elk.example:9200/")
try:
    info = es.info()
except Exception as e:
    print("ELK is not available: {e}".format(e=e))
```

The `.info()` call is actually a wrapper to the REST API, the call is ultimately handled by `urllib3`.

This crashes with the traceback below. If I remove the commented part, the handling is OK. So the issue is indeed introduced by the logging part. Please note that the last line is the `print` from the `except`.

```
GET http://elk.example.com:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.210s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 74, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 222, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
GET http://elk.example.com:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.001s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 74, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 222, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
GET http://elk.example.com:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.001s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 74, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 222, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
GET http://elk.example.com:9200/ [status:N/A request:0.000s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 74, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=False, headers=self.headers, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 222, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1088, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1126, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1084, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 922, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 857, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 155, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 134, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
ELK is not available: ConnectionError(('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))) caused by: ProtocolError(('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed')))
```

It looks like the call was tried several times and (correctly) failed at contacting the server. But how does adding logging changes the way exceptions are handled?

<del>Also: why were the other exceptions not handled by my `try: except:` clause?</del> (see note at the beginning)

*Comment 1: following @Anand S Kumar's comment, I rewrote the code (and changed the question title) to include logging. It is normally better structured, I ripped the relevant part from my modules to reproduce the problem*

*Comment 2: This problem is <del>probably</del> not specific to Elasticsearch, the details are just to give the context (this explains why there is no <kbd>elasticsearch</kbd> tag)*

Comment: Have you configured some kind of logging (or rerouting of stderr) before in the script?

Comment: Ha! yes I did and by adding to the example code the line which imports my logging setup (based on `logging`), I now get the same unhandled crash. I will look into details (I do not want to post walls of code) - would you have an idea what could be the reason (so that I can start with something - what surprises me is that the unhandled code is networking-based, while my logging is just around `FileHandler` and `StreamHandler`)?

Comment: Can you post just the code related to logging here? Maybe I can check

Comment: @AnandSKumar: done. I rewrote the question and the title to better match the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are setting `Debug` level of logger for all loggers, which is causing urllib3 to log the exception. You should try setting logging level for `requests` or `urllib3` to Warning or even higher to suppress the messages from urllib3.

Example -

```
logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Or

```
 logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: This did not work, I needed to set the default level (which is by the way the best thing to do for me, to also cover other possible modules which would log) via `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)`. This said, your idea with logging being the culprit in the first place saved my day, thank you!

Comment: As a side note for me and possible readers: I did not realize at first that the tracebacks I was seeing was **logging** (by `urllib3`) and not unhandled exceptions.